# JS class static member initialization happens before cdn dependency is loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui

I declared this class member but I get the **error `MenuItem` is not defined**.
Obviously the class initialization happens before React or Material-UI finish loading (I'm loading them from their CDN with straight `<script>`s, I assume this **will not happen** when I package them with **npm**, but for now **I have to** do it this way.)
**Is there a way I can prevent this?**

```
    static operators = {
        'auto': [
            <MenuItem key="=" value="=">a=</MenuItem>,
            <MenuItem key="!=" value="!=">b&ne;</MenuItem>,
            <MenuItem key="like" value="like">c like</MenuItem>,
            <MenuItem key="not like" value="not like">d not like</MenuItem>
        ]
    };
```

Comment: The only thing you can do is move that class declaration to a point after the framework stuff is initialized. The declaration is executable code and everything (except instance properties) are evaluated as part of the work done to bring the class into being.

Comment: Also `<script src="whatever"></script>` will stop further evaluation of the HTML container until the script is fetched and fully evaluated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are absolutely correct about you should switch to "bundling" you *js* code, otherwise you'll end up in unmanageable number of race-conditions similar to one you have now.

To provide a quick hacky solution you can take a look on [`onload` HTML event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) and try to do something like

```
<script>
  function loadOperators() {
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.src = "url to your operators component";
    $("head").append(s);
  }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="url to MenuItem" onload="loadOperators()"></script>
```

Comment: Wow that IS hacky. Thanks!